# Android Browser HTML Select Events onclick/onblur not working

Tags: android, mobile, android-browser

Usually when I cant find information on an issue its due to something stupid!  I currently have an Android phone and a select drop down has an onblur event.  This works perfectly on mainstream desktops, but when I use it on my mobile, it appears the browser is ignoring the event.  Is there some other method to getting these events to properly fire?

Some testing code Ive been using:

http://jsfiddle.net/KJUkX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up binding the select to both the onblur and the on change event.  The onchange gets fired even if the first index is selected.  Although now when using a desktop browser it calls the function twice.  Its a small enough function, that I am not concerned.